# ServiceUnavailableException with Neo4j and Spark from Docker

Tags: apache-spark, docker, neo4j, dockerfile

I have created a Docker image for my application which runs with Spark Streaming, Kafka, ElasticSearch, and Kibana. I packaged it into an executable jar file. When I run the application with this command everything works fine as expected (the data starts to be produced):

```
java -cp "target/scala-2.11/test_producer.jar" producer.KafkaCheckinsProducer
```

However, when I run it from docker I get an error of connection to Neo4j, although database runs from docker-compose file:

```
INFO: Closing connection pool towards localhost:7687
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
```

I run my application this way:

```
docker run -v my-volume:/workdir -w /workdir container-name
```

What could cause this problem? And what should I change in my Dockerfile to execute this application?

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ARG ARG_CLASS
ENV MAIN_CLASS $ARG_CLASS
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11.8
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.1.1
ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.2.0
ENV SPARK_DIST spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.6
ENV SPARK_ARCH $SPARK_DIST.tgz

VOLUME /workdir

WORKDIR /opt

# Install Scala
RUN \
  cd /root && \
  curl -o scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
  tar -xf scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
  rm scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
  echo >> /root/.bashrc && \
  echo 'export PATH=~/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc

# Install SBT
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb


# Install Spark
RUN \
    cd /opt && \
    curl -o $SPARK_ARCH http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/$SPARK_ARCH && \
    tar xvfz $SPARK_ARCH && \
    rm $SPARK_ARCH && \
    echo 'export PATH=$SPARK_DIST/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc


EXPOSE 9851 9852 4040 9092 9200 9300 5601 7474 7687 7473

CMD /workdir/runDemo.sh "$MAIN_CLASS"
```

And here is a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  kafka:
    image: spotify/kafka
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
    environment:
    - ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost
  neo4j_db:
    image: neo4j:latest
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import
      - /var/lib/neo4j/data:/data
      - /var/lib/neo4j/conf:/conf
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_active__database=graphImport.db
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:latest
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - docker_elk
    volumes:
        - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  kibana:
    image: kibana:latest
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - docker_elk
volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
  docker_elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From error message - you're trying to connect to `localhost` that is local to your application, not to the host on which it's running.  You need to connect to correct host name inside the Docker network - you don't need to map all ports into your host, you just need to check that all Docker images in the same network.

Comment: I understand that I connect to the wrong host. But how can I check to which one I actually need to connect?

Comment: You need to configure networks correctly, as described in https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks, and then use host names to connect to correct host. You can set it explicitly by adding `hostname` to definition of particular service. Or you can get the name by `docker network inspect network-name`